# Save modified google sheet Template to shared drive instead of each user/accessors personal google drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking to work around the limitation to save an updated template or copy in google sheets to a specified share drive that stores the original file. Could I create a shared drive with all of the users I want to modify the template and put the template in the drive and each of the users access the file and their modifications saved in that shared drive as unique files?

Context: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/22231997?hl=en#

Comment: Yes, you can. Do you want to create the shared drive manually from the user interface or programmatically with Apps Script?

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have the programming skills to write an app script, not sure if there is a standard one for this? But if not, I would say manually given my apps script limitations.

Comment: @ziganotschka did you have insight into whether a script or manually would solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

### You can create a customized shared drive from the user interface

1. Go to https://drive.google.com and click on "Shared drives"
2. Right-click onto the white field and select "New shared drive"
3. Chose a name and click on "Create"
4. At the left top, click on "Add members"

[image]

5. Enter the email addresses of the users you want to add and click on "SEND"

[image]

6. Go on "Manage members" and give to each one personalized permissions, if desired

[image]

[image]

### IF YOU WANT TO SHARE YOUR DRIVE PUBLICLY

Unfortunately currently it is [not possible to share a drive publicly](https://support.google.com/a/thread/13540273?hl=en), however, when you create a file inside the shared drive (or on your drive), you can edit the sharing permission and choose the option that everybody with the link has access to your file. In this case, all you need to do is to share the link with the users.

Keep in mind that the users will not be able to save a copy of the file on the shared drive if they have not been added to the drive.

[image]

[image]

## If you are interested in a Workaround

You can create a [Google Form](https://docs.google.com/forms) and ask the users to submit their file as an attachment to the Google Form. In this case, all the files will be stored on your drive, once the users submit their forms.

Comment: So, I just want to make sure I’m expressing my issue clearly. 
1. Each user will access the template that will be stored on the share drive. 2. They will make their own modifications to the file and save it. 3. I want to ensure that when they save the document it saves on our designated share drive where the template is stored and not on their respective drives.  4. I want to ensure that each file is saved with a unique identifier that it is not the template but instead a modified version of the template. 5. Do I need to add each user to the shared drive for their changes to be stored?

Comment: Each user whom you add as a member. Is this what you want? Other options would be giving access to all domain users or publicly - to any random user who wishes to access.

Comment: I would like to give access publicly to avoid having to add each user as some of the users may gain access from being sent an email by another user and we may miss the process of adding them to the drive.